# easily change horizontal form column alignment in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I create a lot of horizontal forms with bootstrap 4, however it gets really annoying to do a find-replace changing the `col-md-X` for the "left" or label portion of the form when my labels need to get longer or shorter.

I'm considering adding a new empty css class `col-left` for the left column. Also adding a new set of classes that I can put on the `form` element `col-left-md-X`.

```
<form class="col-left-md-4 col-right-md-8">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="FirstName" class="col-form-label col-left">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-right">
            <input class="form-control" name="FirstName" />
            <div class="validation-error hidden"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

the css rules would be like:

```
.col-left-md-4 .col-left {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
}
```

In structuring it like this going to kick me in the rump in some way? Is there a better way of handling this problem? Perhaps something already baked into bootstrap 4?

I just want to change my column sizing once (on the form) and not change it for every single column down the line.

Comment: something like .my2colform label.col-left{
  -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
  flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
  max-width: 33.333333%;
}

.my2colform div.col-right{
  -ms-flex: 0 0 66.666667%;
  flex: 0 0 66.666667%;
  max-width: 66.666667%;
} but i guess i'm missing something, may you post the final layout?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wrote the SCSS to generate all the different classes in css. Feel free to include in your own SCSS builds. Seems to be working extremely well so far.

```
$meta-sizes: 'left', 'mid', 'right';

@mixin make-meta-grid-columns($columns: $grid-columns, $gutter: $grid-gutter-width, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
    // Common properties for all breakpoints
    %grid-column {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 1px; // Prevent columns from collapsing when empty
        padding-right: ($gutter / 2);
        padding-left: ($gutter / 2);
    }

    @each $breakpoint in map-keys($breakpoints) {

        $infix: $breakpoint;

        @each $meta-size in $meta-sizes {
            // Allow columns to stretch full width below their breakpoints
            @for $i from 1 through $columns {
                .col-#{$meta-size}-#{$infix}-#{$i} .col-#{$meta-size} {
                    @extend %grid-column;
                    @include make-col($i, $columns);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@include make-meta-grid-columns();
```